# MySQL time value in query 838:59:59?

Tags: php, mysql

i would like to ask .

I'm trying to add TIME value into mysql database .But the value added in database is **838:59:59**

And it only store into timein column as **838:59:59**. Timeout column result is **00:00:00** value.

The code as below

```
<?php
    $connect      = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "database");
    global $connect;   

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {   
        $timeout            = strtotime('08:30:00');
        $timein             = strtotime('12:30:00');

        $time_out_user      = strtotime($_POST['timeout']);
        $time_in_user       = strtotime($_POST['timein']);

        if(($time_out_user >= $timeout) && ($time_out_user <= $timein))
        {
            echo "Duplicate time";
        }
        else
        {
            $add         = "INSERT INTO table (timeout,timein)
                                       VALUES ('$time_out_user','$time_in_user')";
            $addDateTime = mysqli_query($connect,$add);
            echo "Time added";
        }
    }
?>
<form action="test.php" method="post">  
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Time Out: </td>
            <td><input type ="time" name="timeout" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Time In: </td>
            <td><input type ="time" name="timein" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    

    <p><input class="btnSuccess" type ="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> </p>              
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: what are the column types

Comment: column time for both is TIME .

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simply, it's the maximum that field can hold.

> MySQL retrieves and displays TIME values in 'HH:MM:SS' format (or
>   'HHH:MM:SS' format for large hours values). TIME values may range from
>   '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. The hours part may be so large because
>   the TIME type can be used not only to represent a time of day (which
>   must be less than 24 hours), but also elapsed time or a time interval
>   between two events (which may be much greater than 24 hours, or even
>   negative).

You would probably be better off just using an int field (where the value is stored as seconds difference from the starting time). It's a common practice to have a field that stores seconds elapsed since epoch rather than a datetime field anyway. Else you would need to switch to a [datetime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) field.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html

Comment: i've changed it into datetime type , but the value store is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 for both column timeout and timein

Comment: please update your question with your new table. Also add a sample of the sql generated (eg: use echo to print out the sql)

Comment: i echo the result and the value is "1" . i change into INT type and the value stored is 1478782800 for timeout and 1478794140 for timein .. then, i change it into VARCHAR type , the value is for timeout 1478794140 and timein is 1478797560

Comment: __please update your question with your new table. Also add a sample of the sql generated (eg: use echo to print out the sql)__

Answer (score 0):

You are using **strtotime()**

strtotime() - Parse English textual datetimes into Unix timestamps:

Eg:

```
 echo(strtotime("3 October 2005")); 
output  as 1128312000
```

**HERE TRY THIS**

```
$epoch_time_out_user  =strtotime($_POST['timeout'])- (300*60);

$dt = new DateTime("@$epoch_time_out_user"); 
$time_out_user = $dt->format('H:i:s');

//now $time_out_user has time 
// now you can use **$time_out_user**  in insert query
// do same for  **$time_in_user**  

//FYI : The value (300*60) is depends timezone
```