# How to check each rows in PHP MySQL ?

Tags: php, mysql

i have three row of data mysql database and create column **timeout** and **timein** . it's **VARCHAR** type

row 1 :

**timeout : 0830  , timein : 1030**

row 2 :

**timeout : 1230 , timein : 1730**

row 3 :

**timeout : 1800 , timein : 1900**

i want the code check each row in database before display an error "Duplicate" or adding the data into database table

But the problem is, it only read first row in query. second row and third row doesn't work

```
<?php
    $connect      = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
    global $connect;   

    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){    

        $timeout        = $_POST['timeout'];        
        $timein         = $_POST['timein'];

        $sql       = "SELECT * FROM table";
        $get       = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
        $run       = mysqli_fetch_array($get);

            $timeout_new    = $run['timeout'];
            $timein_new     = $run['timein'];   

                if(($timeout >= $timeout_new) && ($timeout <= $timein_new))
                {
                    echo "Duplicate !";
                }
                else
                {
                    $add         = "INSERT INTO movement (timeout,      timein)
                                               VALUES    ('$timeout',   '$timein')";
                    $addDateTime = mysqli_query($connect,$add);
                    echo "Time added !";
                }       
    }
?>
<form action="dd.php" method="post">    
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Time out : </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="timeout" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Time in : </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="timein" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    

    <p><input class="btnSuccess" type ="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> </p>              
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use a `foreach()` to looop through the results from the database, as it runs through them check to see if they exist in the result array.

Comment: can you show me how ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL time value in query 838:59:59?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521703/mysql-time-value-in-query-8385959)

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is wrong, isn't it?

```
if(($timeout >= $timeout_new) && ($timeout <= $timein_new))
```

Shouldn't it be

```
if(($timeout >= $timeout_new) && ($timein <= $timein_new))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the control in question

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){    

$timeout        = $_POST['timeout'];        
$timein         = $_POST['timein'];

$sql       = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE timeout >= '{$_POST['timeout']}' AND timeout <= '{$_POST['timein']}'";
$get       = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  


if(mysql_num_rows($get))
{
    echo "Duplicate !";
}
else
{
    $add         = "INSERT INTO movement (timeout,      timein)
                               VALUES    ('$timeout',   '$timein')";
    $addDateTime = mysqli_query($connect,$add);
    echo "Time added !";
}       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $run as $row )
{
  $timeout_new  = $row[ 'timeout' ];
  $timein_new   = $row[ 'timein' ];   

  if( ( $timeout >= $timeout_new ) && ( $timein <= $timein_new ) )
  {
    echo "Duplicate !";
  }
  else
  {
    $add = "INSERT INTO movement (timeout, timein) VALUES ('$timeout', '$timein')";
    $addDateTime = mysqli_query($connect,$add);
    echo "Time added !";
  }
}
```

This is not tested so I can not say for sure it will work first time but it will give you an idea of what you need to look at.  You are currently only looking at the first result.  You need to loop through the results and check them.

Comment: how to select it ?

Comment: How to select what?

Comment: i don't know how to add for loop . i tried to add foreach loop . it turns out to add multiple data inside the database

Comment: If you having issues using loops then you need to do some research - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_loop_types.htm